# How to deploy angular universal application on iisnode

Tags: angular, angular-universal, iisnode

I have created the angular universal application but when I try to deployment on iisnode server it given the exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <match url="/*" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

But it returns the internal server error for accessing the site. Can any please help me

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite Module must be installed on your IIS Server. If it's not installed, you can download it from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337

Answer (score 0):

In my case I saw that something is missing in server.ts file.

```
app.listen(PORT);
```